# Mail getting stuck in OWA Draft (Newly Installed Exchange Server 2019)

Tags: email, exchange-server-2019

I have Installed fresh Exchange Server 2019 and I got stuck in Mail Flow (Internal). I have made one user named Employee 1 and trying to send mails from OWA from administrator account. But mails are getting stuck in draft. Please help me through this.

Thanks You.

Answer (score 1):

Finally got the solution for this...

This issue occurs when your Exchange server DNS not properly installed. In Exchange server DNS you have to put DNS IP of Domain Controller and Alternate DNS column should be blank. Restart your server and issue will be resolved.